# Add right padding to text inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed sized div. Text inside the div can overflow it and it doesn't wrap.

```
<div style="background-color: #7B92D3;" class="div-2">
    <p id="text">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
</div>

.div-2 {
    width: 150px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

The problem is that I want left and right paddings but only left padding applies. How can I add space to right side?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've an overflow, the text will be displayed in front of your padding. So you either need an additional `div` or apply the overflow to the `p`.

```css
.div-2 {
    width: 150px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.div-2 p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px yellow solid;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #7B92D3;" class="div-2">
    <p id="text">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
</div>
```

Note: I added a yellow border just to make the `p` visible.

Note 2 (edit): The solution with adding borders mentioned by Sam will work, but you won't be able to add an additional border to that div.

Answer (score 2):

When `overflow:hidden,` is set the text will overflow into padding. You can create a transparent border to solve this problem.

```css
.div-2 {
    width: 150px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left:10px solid transparent;
    border-right:10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #7B92D3;" class="div-2">
    <p id="text">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
</div>
```